# How to suppress * as a wildcard, instead interpret as character?

Tags: python

I am working with files that have an asterisk in the filenames. 
I have a list of certain ones I am interested in but whenever I loop through them, the `"*"` in the name is interpreted as a wildcard.

For example: filenames are `A*01:02` and `A*02`.

I only want to extract `A*02` but the `"*"` is interpreted as a wildcard and both `A*01:02` and `A*02` are used.

How can I suppress the wildcard `"*"` and interpret it as a character instead?

Comment: Please submit a [minimal_reproducible_example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is a shell issue, not a Python issue.

Comment: What Python code are you doing that is interpreting `*` characters as wildcards?

Comment: To be clear, when the shell starts a Python program, **wildcard expansion is done *by the shell*, before Python is ever started**. There is nothing at all you can do in your Python code to prevent it, because it already happened before Python was invoked.

Comment: So what do you suggest I should do?
I am looping through the files in python and passing on the file names to a shell command. I tried removing (import glob) from my script, but it didn't help (i.e. the files were not opened and no output was generated). I tried replacing * with blackslash* before passing on the shell command, but that didn't help either (same, files didn't open and no output was generated).

Answer (score 0):

Quote `"A*02"` or use a backslash as in `A\*02`.

Comment: ...in *Python* code? You're showing shell syntax.

Comment: The OP has a shell issue. Python opens files with a `*` just naturally; it would need `glob()` to expand the wildcard.